# T-SQL Query for counting ongoing events per given intervals

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

We have events with a date range:

```
Event | Begin | End
------|-------|------
a     | 11:30 | 12:15
b     | 10:30 | 13:15
c     | 11:30 | 13:30
```

Visualized as a timetable:

```
a)         |---|
b)   |---------------|
c)         |-----------|
  |-----|-----|-----|-----|
10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00
```

We want an efficient query for counting ongoing events on given timestamps. In this example we want them per hour. Like this:

```
Time             | OnGoing
-----------------|--------
2014-02-06 10:00 | 0
2014-02-06 11:00 | 1
2014-02-06 12:00 | 3
2014-02-06 13:00 | 2
2014-02-06 14:00 | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a driver table with all hours, then join to that:

```
;WITH cal AS (SELECT CAST('10:00:00' AS TIME) dt
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT DATEADD(hour,1,dt)
              FROM cal
              WHERE dt < '14:00:00')
SELECT dt, COUNT(DISTINCT Event) OnGoing
FROM  cal a
LEFT JOIN Table1 b
 ON a.dt BETWEEN b.[Begin] AND b.[End]
GROUP BY dt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/327aa/8/0)

Adjust the range in the `cal` cte to fit your preferences.  I notice your sample output shows a `datetime`, so you could cast `begin` and `end` as `TIME` in your join and add a `DATE` portion to your `select` and `group by`, or you could alter the cte to be full `datetime`. If spanning more than 100 units in your cte, you'll need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the very end of your query.